# How to load another page with AJAX after input code entered?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to load another document(blade.php) with AJAX after a certain code is inputed in a Laravel view. But the code will need to change according to the page for example for Page 1(testview.blade.php) the code entered into the  to pass to Page 2(testview2.blade.php) should be CODE1 and for Page 2(testview2.blade.php) to pass to Page 3(testview3.blade.php) the code should be CODE2. How could I do this? is this possible with a Controller? Can a controller return something as AJAX or i need a script?

**testview.blade.php:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <p>Page 1</p>
  <img src="{{ asset('img/img1.png') }}"/>

  <form action="#" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" id="code" name="code"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**testview2.blade.php:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <p>Page 2</p>
  <img src="{{ asset('img/img2.png') }}"/>

  <form action="#" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" id="code" name="code"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**testview3.blade.php:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <p>Page 3</p>
  <img src="{{ asset('img/img3.png') }}"/>

  <form action="#" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" id="code" name="code"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can hide or show the view using JS, `href` is also an option as per condition. Can you please show your code of controller and AJAX?

Comment: My controller doesn't have anything and my actual script code is a button that uses .show() and .hide() from javascript. I barely understand ajax so i wanted a hint on how to do it. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: you can put your  code of `form` in single `blade` file. And by using button you can call `ajax` code, according to your coditions of input you can `show` and `hide` your `forms`. Can we have a proper functionality in description/

Comment: Sorry i dont understan what you are asking, what should I do?